# New favicon too small

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, favicon

The new favicon seems not only smaller than necessary (not using the available space), but positively *squished*, compared to the old icon and the Meta icon:

[image: favicons]

- Left: new icon
- Middle: old icon (chat.stackoverflow.com)
- Right: Meta icon

Comment: Plus it's in grayscale. Maybe - just maybe - to make it harder to find our opened Stack Overflow pages amongst other tabs. Thanks!

Comment: @Smuuf Mine isn’t greyscale (the *Meta* icon is).

Comment: Well, now I look like a complete tool. Still - the actual SO favicon *is* needlesly small.

Answer (score 2):

We're still not sure what happened here, but at some point the icon-16 and icon-32 files used to generate the favicons and sprites automatically got replaced with smaller versions. This happens in a batch on the designer machines before upload - so somewhere there's a slightly more whitespaced version that snuck in the overall update commit.

This was not intentional. I have reverted these files, rebuilt our favicons and sprites, and a build/deployment has just completed. With a hard refresh you should see the change.